# Color Python keyword arguments in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs, pycharm, syntax-highlighting, colorize

Is it possible to colorize Python keyword arguments in emacs?

For example, Github and PyCharm do this:

- [Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irP2F.png)
- [PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8KG2.png)

How I can get the same behaviour in Emacs? Does exist a `face` for this that I can configure?

Just in case, I'm using `material` theme.

Comment: I know you asked this question a long time ago, but did you get an answer? I really want to do the same and I don't find anything... :(

Answer (score 1):

Syntax highlighting should be built-in and on by default as of emacs 22.1 and later (according to [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Turning-on-syntax-highlighting.html) documentation). It seems that maybe `font-lock-mode` got turned off for you somehow.

Try `M-x font-lock-mode`.

This is what it looks like disabled for me with the material theme (and no other packages involved):

[image: font-lock-mode disabled]

And when I enable it:

[image: font-lock-mode enabled]

Comment: Material theme is working properly in my emacs configuration, but "python keyword arguments" are not colorized at all. Does it work for you? Can you share an screenshot with a function call with multiple keyword arguments as I did? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't actually catch that part of your original question! But this link might help: [How to Write a Emacs Major Mode for Syntax Coloring](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_syntax_coloring.html)